# Reed-Solomon encoding and decoding implementation example in Java

Tags: java, reed-solomon

I need to encode and decode some text using Reed-Solomon error correction codes. Implementation should be in Java.

I have gone through Sean Owen's implementation classes but was not able to construct these classes with a working example.

Can somebody please post an working example of Reed-Solomon error correction codes or any reference links.

Answer (score 3):

this is a bit late, but there is a fully working example in Java on github here:

https://github.com/alexbeutel/Error-Correcting-Codes/tree/master/src

It features the following classes:

- **Decoder.java**          <== R-S Decoder class
- **Encoder.java**          <== R-S Encoder class
- **ErrorCodesMain.java**   <== Fully working example
- **GF257.java**            <== Galois Fields(257) class
- **GF28.java**             <== Galois Fields(2^8) class

To build the project from the command line:

```
javac ErrorCodesMain.java Decoder.java Encoder.java GF257.java GF28.java
```

To run it:

```
java ErrorCodesMain
```

Here is the program's output:

```
# of Generators of GF(2^8): 128
# of Generators of GF(257): 128
Generator: 206
Erasures: 38, 1, 7, 15, 28, 16, 29, 28, 7, 8, 

OUTPUT FROM O(nk) IN GF(2^8): Hello, my name is Alex Beutel.
FFT OUTPUT DECODED: Hello, my name is Alex Beutel.
OUTPUT FROM O(nk) IN GF(257): Hello, my name is Alex Beutel.
```

Comment: This looks familiar, did I not post a ocmment about the under the question ?